# Figuring out probability of multiple events in a series.

Tags: probability

If there is a probability event A occurs 1/40 times and event b occurs 1/120 times, what is the probability of event a occurring 6 times and event b occurring 8 times (combined 14 events occur between a and b) in 221 total attempts? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Event A occurring at least 6 times or exactly 6 times, likewise Event B

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! Can you tell us what you've tried so far? Also, in those 221 events, how many of each $A$ and $B$ is better tested?

Comment: At least for both

Comment: and each one is tested in each attempt, but they can't occur together (that makes it complex :(), so if event a occurs, it negates the chance for event b, but if event a doesn't occur, event b has can, so the 6 times event a occurred, event b had a 0% chance

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 Events, A with $P(A) = \dfrac{3}{120}$, B with $P(B) = \dfrac{1}{120}$ and C with $P(C)=\dfrac{116}{120}$
$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$

You need 6 A's, 8 B's and 207 C's. The probability of one occurrence of this is ${P(A)}^6.{P(B)}^8{P(C)}^{207}$ but you must take in account the permutations of this events

$\dfrac{221\,!}{6\,!8\,!207\,!}$

Then, the final answer is:$\dfrac{221\,!}{6\,!8\,!207\,!}{P(A)}^6.{P(B)}^8{P(C)}^{207}$